# Expo application doesn't get changes in .env file

Tags: react-native, expo, dotenv

I have an Expo managed react native application. I created my `.env` file in the root of my project, installed `react-native-dotenv` and set up `babel` to use it. After a while I managed to get it to work.

I have my environment variable
`ENDPOINT=http://127.0.0.1:8000/api`

and i use it with
`process.env.ENDPOINT`

After a while I decided to test the android version of the app, so i changed the endpoint url to my LAN ip and restarted the server. The problem is that even after restarting the server, the cache and the computer, when I call `process.env.ENDPOINT` it keeps the first url I set.

Here's a list of the things i tried:

- restarting the server
- restarting the server and the cache
- restarting the whole computer
- change the variable name to `REACT_APP_ENDPOINT` as many suggested (I get undefined, it's still stuck to `ENDPOINT`)
- empty expo cache

The strange thing is that I already changed that same variable twice (from `127.0.0.1:8000` to `127.0.0.1:8080` and back for a problem with backend) and had the same problem, but it went away by itself after a couple of minutes (and server restarts).
This time I've been trying to get it to work for 7 hours and nothing has changed.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and managed to run the app with .env changes after using the following command.

expo r -c

reference: https://github.com/goatandsheep/react-native-dotenv/issues/75#issuecomment-728055969

Answer (score 1):

You can run:

```
npx expo start --clear
```

It will clear the cache from the bundler and then you'll be able to run it.

Answer (score -1):

After a couple hundred more tests I gave up and implemented a "custom" solution, without any external library:

- Switched `.env` files to TypeScript files (E.g. `.env.development` -> `env.development.ts`)
- Set up an object named env that has all environmental variables as properties

```
export const env = {
       VAR1: 'foo',
       ...
    }
```

- Imported this constant inside the application entry point (in my case `App.tsx`)
- Inside the main constructor assign env to `global.env`
- Use `global.env` instead of `process.env`

Not sure if this is the best practice, but solved my problem for now, works like a charm and doesn't require me to reload my application at every change. I'm a bit concerned by the security aspect of having the environment in a global variable inside a js project, so any suggestion is still welcome